# How to design a consistent UI for mapped items that might not have all the fields at certain times?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, web, tailwind-css

So, I have a products item data fetched from a database and I am trying to map them and display them with the same UI. the problem i am facing is that, some of the fetched items miss some fields(for example,some fields don't have a discount field), the lengths of item name might vary etc. So, since The UI i made is common for all,when there is no discount field,it becomes empty and the contents of ui become compressed up decreasing the whole ui's height and this makes the whole ui ugly. how can i solve this? I have attached the picture and the code below. thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMrqz.png)

```
interface SingleProductProps{
    item: Product;
  }
function ItemSingleDisplay({item}:{item:Product}) {
  console.log("The item type and its contents are: ",typeof item,item)
  return (
        <div className="flex flex-col p-2 border rounded-lg focus:outline-none hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-lg transition-shadow bg-slate-100">
            <Link href={{pathname:"/pages/userPage/Details",query: { passedDetail: JSON.stringify(item)}}} className="flex flex-col gap-1">
              {item.sale ==="Yes" &&<h3 className="absolute bg-slate-500 rounded-lg px-2">Sale</h3>}
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center bg-red-300 py-2 aspect-[4/3]">
                {item.itemImages.length>0 && <Image src={`/${item.itemImages[0]?.split("\\").pop()}`} alt={`Image`} width={80} height={80}/>}
              </div>
              <div className="p-1">
              <h2 className=" font-bold text-lg">{item.productName}</h2>
              {item.sale ==="Yes" && 
                <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                    <h3 className=" bg-red-400 inline-block p-1 rounded-lg">{item.priceDrop}% off </h3>
                    <h3>Previous Price: <span className=" bg-white line-through">${parseFloat(item.price) + parseFloat(item.price)*(parseFloat(item.priceDrop))/100}</span></h3>
                </div>
              }
                <h3 className=" font-bold text-lg">${item.price}</h3>
              </div>
            </Link>
            <div className=" flex flex-row gap-1 justify-between">
              <button className="items-center justify-center"><AddToCart action="Add To Cart" /></button>
              <button><AddToCart action="Buy Now" /></button>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default ItemSingleDisplay
```

and then it's used here

```
interface ProductProps{
    dataDisplay: Product[];
  }
const SlideItemShow: React.FC<ProductProps> = ({dataDisplay}) =>
    { 
    const [startIndex,setIndex] = useState(0)
    const moveLeft =() =>{
        setIndex(startIndex+5)
    }
    const moveRight =() =>{
        setIndex(startIndex -5)
    }
    console.log(startIndex)
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row relative">
        <button disabled={startIndex === 0} onClick={moveRight} className={`absolute left-0 border p-2 rounded z-10 h-16 w-16 mt-32 ${startIndex===0 ?" bg-gray-400 bg-opacity-50":" bg-gray-600"}`}>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 ml-2">
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M7.72 12.53a.75.75 0 010-1.06l7.5-7.5a.75.75 0 111.06 1.06L9.31 12l6.97 6.97a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-7.5-7.5z" clipRule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
        </button>
        <div className='flex flex-row gap-5'>
            {dataDisplay?.slice(startIndex,startIndex +5).map((item,index)=>(
                <div key={index}>
                    <ItemSingleDisplay item={item} />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
            <button disabled ={startIndex+5 >= (dataDisplay.length)} onClick={moveLeft} className={ `absolute right-0 p-2 border rounded h-16 w-16 mt-32 z-10 ${startIndex+5<(dataDisplay.length)?" bg-gray-600":" bg-gray-100"} `}>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 ml-2">
                    <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M16.28 11.47a.75.75 0 010 1.06l-7.5 7.5a.75.75 0 01-1.06-1.06L14.69 12 7.72 5.03a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l7.5 7.5z" clipRule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SlideItemShow
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the CSS layout.
The Basic idea is to

1. Have a fixed height and width for your product box. The same goes for your product image as well
2. For the name field, either clip the name if it's overflow. You can also use multiple lines based on your UI preference.
3. For the discount, It depends on how you want to keep your UI.
   If you want to keep the price and action buttons in the same line, keep one fixed height div. If a discount is available show that else keep empty so your UI will be consistent. If you don't want to show an empty box then you can also show a 0% discount placeholder. So mainly this depends on your UI preference.

Adding one [basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-chihiro-prg7dw) for you to understand it better.

(p.s I have used some static data for the example and have kept the border for your understanding. And always provide codesandbox links in your question so someone can look at the running example and can help you better).